# How to setState base64 string as image in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I received a base64 string as image from the server and I need to set src of html img tag. When I set the state of img in useEffect hook it doesn't show in browser.

In Chrome browser it gives me net::ERR_INVALID_URL error in the javascript console.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Captcha(props) {
  const [captchaImg, setCaptchaImg] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
     setCaptchaImg("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
  }, []);

  return (
   <div>
      <img
       alt="captcha"
       id="dnt-captcha-img"
       src={`data:image/png;base64,${captchaImg}`}
      />
   </div>

  );
}

export default Captcha;
```

Comment: Why did you edit the answer into you post? Now there's no question here anymore, because your code already works, which means this post has no value and is going to get closed.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the correct `Content-type`, `Content-encoding` and `charset` (eg. `data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64`):

```js
/*depends on what you want to pass, might not be needed here*/
setCaptchaImg("data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
return <div>
  <img
     alt="captcha"
     id="dnt-captcha-img"
     src=data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64, {captchaImg}
  />
</div>
```